# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for JSON files

Tags: php, http, http-headers, cors

I kept a JSON files in Server A, ip : 111.111.111.111/folder1/a.json

From Server B [ ip : 444.444.444.444 ], I am trying to access that JSON file , I received the result below:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://111.111.111.111/a.json' from origin 'http://444.444.444.444' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I wrote the following code in 111.111.111.111/index.php , but I am receiving the same error:

```
<?php

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://444.444.444.444"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

?>
```

Accessing JSON using below JavaScript code :

```
$.getJSON("http://111.111.111.111/folder1/a.json", (data) => {  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Access-Control policy needs to be set on the same URL than the requested ressource.

What I mean is that if you're going to request access to `/folder1/a.json`, then the Access-Control headers needs to be set on the requests for this specific URL.

You could add these headers via your server (Apache / Nginx / ...) or create a php script like the one you made that sets those headers and returns the json file content (i.e. `/folder1/a.json.php`).

BTW your code isn't valid PHP, use the [`header(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

You coud use a script like this:

```php
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://444.444.444.444/*');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    die(file_get_contents('a.json'));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, do i need to set these codes in client or server ? means do i need to add the code in 111.111.111.111 or 444.444.444.444

Comment: PHP is server side only, so you'd need to do that on your server A.

Comment: thanks, so i am writing code in correct address 111.111.111.111 , do  i need to add code like this : `<?php
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://111.111.111.111/folder1/a.json
?>` ?

Comment: Like I said you should use the [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.
The allow origin header list pages that are allowed to request the current ressource, so you should add server B in the allow origin header (`http://444.444.444.444/*`)

Comment: thanks,  i wrote like this : `<?php
header('Location: http:/444.444.444.444');
?>`

Comment: The `Location` header is used for redirection, What you want is `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://444.444.444.444/*');`

Comment: sorry, is this correct : `<?php
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://444.444.444.444
?>` ?

Comment: What you want is `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://444.444.444.444/*');`

Comment: thanks, what * will represent in your comment after  444 ?

Comment: This means any URL that starts with `http://444.444.444.444/`

Comment: i saw your updated answer, you mentioned `a.json` in code, but i have many hundreds of files, so i need to allow access of complete ip : 111 to ip : 444

Comment: also please tell where actually i need to add that code in 111 server, means do i need to add in index.php or in the file that i mentioned json path ? please join chat here : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96967/cors

Comment: Then I would suggest to do it via your server configuration, or use a single php script to access all your files.

Comment: means what i  i need is to give access of all json files present in ip : 111 access to ip 444

Comment: i kept the json files in [link1](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/) , i am trying to access in [link2](http://139.59.28.197/editor.php?page=phone) , now please tell do i need to add code in link1 server ? if so do i need to add code in index.php file ? or any other file ?

Comment: You need to put the Access Control headers on the server (link1).  However, if you have multiple files you need to either use a mechanism to serve multiple json files from a single php script or configure your server software (Apache / Nginx) to add access control headers to requests made to the json files on your server.

Comment: i dont want to do server configuration as because if we move to another server again, we need to do.... if possible, can you please give me complete php code  ?

Comment: means actually i am writing all json files in single php file, in that case if i pass php file , is that enough ? means in [this link](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/editor.php) i am passing json files.....

Comment: I won't give the code but I told you what you need to do. You need to create a single PHP script that will serve all your JSON files (you could take the name of the file as a query-string parameter, be carefull not to give access to unwanted ressources)

Comment: please join [this another chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96563/discussion-between-lenniey-and-matthias)

Comment: yes, i am already passing all json files in single file called editor.php , in that case if i give access of editor.php to ip : 444, is that enough ?

Comment: Yes, it should be fine.

Comment: thanks, sorry for troubling you lot, now [this is editor.php](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/server/editor.php) , i need to give access of that editor.php file to this ]link2](http://139.59.28.197/editor.php?page=phone) , please tell what code i need to use ? because i wrote this code in index.php , but it didt worked for me : `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http:// 139.59.28.197/editor.php?page=phone');` or do i need to add this code in editor.php file only ?

Comment: You need to set the relevant Access Control headers on the ressource you are trying to access, so yes, you need to put it in the `editor.php` script.

Comment: now i wrote code in editor.php file : `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://139.59.28.197/');` is this correct ? i am trying to access in [this link](http://139.59.28.197/editor.php?page=phone) , but in console it gave cors error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96970/discussion-between-navir-and-vickey-colors).

Comment: Thanks , i got solution by this : `sudo a2enmod headers`